# How to color by a factor column using Scatterplot 3d in R?

Tags: r, 3d

I'm really struggling with plotting a 3D scatterplot, even after looking at a variety of tutorials, with this [website](http://www.sthda.com/english/wiki/impressive-package-for-3d-and-4d-graph-r-software-and-data-visualization) probably being the most helpful.

I have my code down below for my 3D graph. Basically, I just want to three colors to be that of my classification column in R. The label for 211 should be "high", the label for 122 should be "low", and the label for 0 should be "intermediate".

So basically, I want to color by my grouping variable of "Classification".

```
library("plot3D")

# regression


x <- hr.1 <- average_with_clusters$MeanHR
y <- tb.1 <- average_with_clusters$MeanTb
z <- pa.1 <- average_with_clusters$MeanPA

fit <- lm(z ~ x + y)

grid.lines = 26
x.pred <- seq(min(x), max(x), length.out = grid.lines)
y.pred <- seq(min(y), max(y), length.out = grid.lines)
xy <- expand.grid( x = x.pred, y = y.pred)
z.pred <- matrix(predict(fit, newdata = xy), 
                 nrow = grid.lines, ncol = grid.lines)

fitpoints <- predict(fit)


scatter3D(x, y, z, 
          pch = 18, col.var = as.integer(average_with_clusters$Body_temp_Cluster), 
          col = c("#1B9E77", "#D95F02", "#7570B3"),
          pch = 18, ticktype = "detailed",
          theta = 10, phi = 20, 
          main = "Cluster data", 
          xlab = "Heart Rate",
          ylab ="Body Temperature", 
          zlab = "Percent Active",
          colkey = list(at = c(2, 3), side = 1, 
                        addlines = TRUE, length = 0.5, width = 0.5,
                        labels = c("high", "low", "intermediate")),
          surf = list(x = x.pred, y = y.pred, z = z.pred,  
                      facets = NA, fit = fitpoints))

Turtle <- c("R3L1", "R3L11", "R3L12", "R3L2", 
            "R3L4", "R3L9", "R4L8", "R8L1", 
            "R8L4", "R8NAT123")

text3D(x, y, z,  labels = Turtle,
       add = TRUE, colkey = FALSE, cex = 0.5)
```

I'm attaching my whole data set because it is very small.

```
average_with_clusters <- tibble::tibble(
  Turtle = c(
    "R3L1", "R3L11", "R3L12", "R3L2", "R3L4", "R3L9", "R4L8", "R8L1",
    "R8L4", "R8NAT123"
  ),
  MeanHR = c(
    21.6886497081712, 18.9328813559322, 17.6588833700082, 8.95548715207506,
    12.9387129461585, 20.4428053977273, 15.0832100108814, 16.4188964193433,
    15.075755022071, 26.6644957856944
  ),
  MeanTb = c(
    20.2662236689815, 22.9743998088286, 18.3861903935185, 18.8428125,
    21.9617008101852, 20.4919618055556, 19.1270783213045, 20.1088958333333,
    22.4328795138889, 22.0789053819444
  ),
  MeanPA = c(
    18.6825667236286, 39.037800687567, 20.4402515724717, 16.780045351542,
    18.5773074665079, 25.7482993198571, 26.2546222928209, 13.1302521011765,
    17.9698216735597, 42.1985815619149
  ),
  Heart_Rate_Cluster = c("2", "1", "3", "2", "2", "1", "2", "1", "1", "2"),
  Body_temp_Cluster = c("1", "2", "1", "1", "2", "2", "1", "2", "2", "2"),
  Percent_Active_Cluster = c("1", "2", "1", "1", "2", "2", "1", "1", "2", "1"),
  Classification = factor(c("211", "122", "0", "211", "0", "122", "211", "0", "122", "0")),
)
```

Please help me if possible!! I'm currently getting this which I know isn't possible because there isn't a grouping with just one variable.

[image]